# How do i add or remove attribute to html/ionic component depending on boolean value?

Tags: html, input, angular7, ionic4

I've an input tag with attribute formControlName

```
<ion-input type="text"
           autocomplete
           autocorrect
           formControlName="title"></ion-input>
```

My template file also have bool variable **dataLoaded**

I want to check my Bool variable and only add my attribute **formControlName** in my  when bool variable is true.
else the attribute should be removed.

I want this with out using extra Js.

i tried.

```
formControlName="dataLoaded ? 'title' : null"

[formControlName]="dataLoaded ? 'title' : null"
```

but this gives error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `*ngIf`:

```
<ion-input type="text"
           *ngIf="dataLoaded"
           autocomplete
           autocorrect
           formControlName="title"></ion-input>
<ion-input type="text"
           *ngIf="!dataLoaded"
           autocomplete
           autocorrect></ion-input>
```

only one input will be rendered by DOM depending on `dataLoaded` value